# Get the value of a Drop list while hovering the options without clicking with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the value of a Drop list while hovering the options with the mouse without clicking (selecting) using JS or jQuery?

Ex.

```
List of Stuff
 -Dog
 -Cat
 -Bird
```

[image]

When I move my mouse around the options of the droplist, it will tell me that my item is being highligted.

Comment: I think you might need to create/implement a custom drop list component.

Comment: is there any component that shows a preview of the item Im currently hovering? ex. I hover on Cat and it will display a pic of a cat in another div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with standard selects, but if you need the desired effect badly enough you can create your own select components and back them with hidden inputs.

Comment: is there any component that shows a preview of the item Im currently hovering? ex. I hover on Cat and it will display a pic of a cat in another div

Comment: There are various pre-built components out there, ex: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns but I can't speak to their specifics since I generally roll my own. They aren't terribly difficult to build if you've got some time.